# ORM Django Many to Many

Tags: django, view, orm, model, many-to-many

I am trying to retrieve ONE order ID for ticket/s purchased a user made. When I put `Order.objects.all()`, it shows all the order ID from the Db, but I am trying to retrieve just one `order ID`. When I instead query: `Order.objects.filter(buyer=Ticket.objects.get(id='tic_id'))`----it gives me an error:

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'tic_id'.

Can someone please verify if my models are correct and how to query to obtain just one `order ID` and not all of the `order ID`s? For example, it currently shows:

> "Your order number is 123456789101112131415" and I am aiming it to show "order number is 11"; Thank you, I appreciate your patience!

models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Ticket(models.Model):
    venue=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    quantity=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    price=models.DecimalField(default=25.00, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    loop=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    purchaser = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="purchases", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Order(models.Model):
    full_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cc_number=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    exp_date=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    cvc=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    buyers=models.ManyToManyField(Ticket, related_name="bought_tickets")
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

views.py

```
def process(request):
Order.objects.create(full_name=request.POST['full_name'], cc_number=request.POST['cc_number'],exp_date=request.POST['exp_date'], cvc=request.POST['cvc'])    
return redirect('/checkout')

def checkout(request):
    context={
        "user":User.objects.get(id=request.session['user_id']),

        "tickets": Ticket.objects.filter(purchaser=User.objects.get(id=request.session['user_id'])).annotate(total=Sum(F('quantity') * F('price'),  output_field=FloatField())).annotate(tax=ExpressionWrapper(F('quantity') * F('price')*0.0725,  output_field=FloatField())).annotate(total_price=ExpressionWrapper(F('quantity') * F('price') + F('tax'),  output_field=FloatField())),

        "order":Order.objects.filter(buyer=Ticket.objects.get(id='tic_id'))
    }
    return render(request, 'first_app/checkout.html', context)
```

checkout.html

```
<p class="lead">Your order number is:<strong>{% for o in order %}{{o.id}}{% endfor %}</strong><p class="lead">with ticket number:</p><strong>{% for ticket in tickets %}{{ticket.id}}{% endfor %}</strong>
```

Comment: How do you want to identify which order to show?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Order number ID for tickets purchased or Ticket number ID. It shows the Ticket ID as well as the order ID---but it gives me a list of order IDs when I do Order.objects.all() and I am only trying to show one order number for every ticket/tickets purchased (Ticket ID)

Comment: But the relationship between Order and Ticket is many-to-many. So each order has *many* tickets, and each ticket has *many* orders. Given an order, how do you know which of its tickets you want to show?

Comment: I think you're helping me clarify the relationship: I guess the user can request 1-8 tickets (one to many) and it gives a Ticket ID. But since the user has to pay the Ticket ID--it comes with an order ID. You may be correct the relationship may not make sense; should I just leave the Order ID as one-one relationship with Ticket ID? What would you suggest? Sorry I am very new on this, but I appreciate the clarification.

Comment: Unless you are trying to set up a con job, every ticket should only be orderable once? Thus a foreign key on ticket pointing at the order it is part of makes more sense. If you _are_ trying to set up a con job by selling the same ticket multiple times, and thus need a M2M, you are better off not having a database at all? Evidence and all?

Comment: @CoffeeBasedLifeform Should I keep Order as a model of its own and no relation? No foreign key/M2M or in other words, eliminate the buyers field? Also, when Order.objects.all()--it gives me a list of all the order IDs--is there a way to only obtain one order ID per time the user purchased the ticket/s? For example, it shows: "Thank you, your order is 12345678910" and wanting to just show "Thank you, your order is 11" (for instance)--just one order ID showing?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a str to the param `id` `Ticket.objects.get(id='tic_id')`. I supose that `tic_id` is a variable so you need to use it without quotes `Ticket.objects.get(id=tic_id)`

Comment: It is a variable. I defined it elsewhere in my views perhaps.I am trying to figure how to show one order ID instead of a list of order IDs. Would I need to edit the Jinja in HTML or views?

Comment: Remove the quotes, instead of `id='tic_id'` use `id=tic_id`. `id` is expecting an `int` but you are passing a `str`.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the relationships in your schema are slightly off.
It is now:
[image]

What it should be:
[image]

You would then get the order id with `Order.objects.get(buyer=user_id).values_list('pk', flat = True)[0]` (WRONG: see update!) and a ticket's owner is given through the order it was bought with.
If something doesn't feel quite right, it's always a good idea to grab pen and paper and start drawing some diagrams.

---

UPDATE:
The models would roughly look like this:

```
class Order:
    # one order can only have one buyer, but Users may have many orders
    buyer = ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'orders') 

class Ticket:
    # one ticket can only have one order, but many tickets may be ordered at once
    order = ForeignKey(Order, related_name = 'tickets')

    def get_owner(self):
        # Returns the user that has ordered this ticket.          
        return self.order.buyer
```

Also I just realized that you still won't get a single order from `Order.objects.get(buyer=user_id)` as a user may have more than one order. 
One approach would be to redirect to an url containing the created order or to store that order in the session. 
Or just:

```
def process(request):
    order = # ... create order
    context = {'order': order, # ... other stuff }
    return render(request, 'first_app/checkout.html', context)
```

Comment: I think your models make more sense. The user is attached to the ticket ID (1-many tickets) (one to many relationship) So could I do the Order relationship with Ticket as foreign key instead of M2M? For example : ```class Order(models.Model):
    full_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cc_number=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    exp_date=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    cvc=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    buyers=models.ForeignKey(Ticket, related_name="bought_tickets")
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

Comment: No, the other way around. I have updated my answer.